# Tessellating a BSpline patch using a triangle list (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, bezier, bspline

As the title describes I am trying to tessellate a BSpline patch using a triangle list.

Here is an image of my patch from the front, which looks exactly how it should.

[image: patch front]

My problem is the rear of the patch, which gives this effect:

[image: patch rear]

As you can see the previous row of triangles are connecting to the new row that is being drawn. I have tried various ways of trying to avoid this such as increasing the index value by 1 when it reaches the end of the row. The only quick fix I could find is putting each row in a separate loop (with the loop range because the size of that row), which is not intuitive at all.

Here is the code for the drawing of my patch:

```
void drawBSplinePatch1(std::vector<int>& sample_elements_out, const int samples)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= 379; i++)
    {
        // first triangle
        sample_elements_out.push_back(i);
        sample_elements_out.push_back(i + 1);
        sample_elements_out.push_back(i + samples);

        // second triangle
        sample_elements_out.push_back(i  + samples);
        sample_elements_out.push_back(i + 1);
        sample_elements_out.push_back(i + samples + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it not intuitive to have separate loops for the rows and columns? Sounds straight forward to me...? You probably should post the loop(s) if you want people to understand your question...

Comment: It's not just that it's not intuitive, I would end up with way over 100 loops which would eventually exceed the limit of loops allowed in one file.

Comment: So you did not nest the loops? I'd expect this to be exactly two nested loops. Maybe post part of the working version, too -- this will probably allow people to show how to write this in a more compact form. With the current code, it's hard to guess the correct indices for breaking up the rows.

Comment: Sorry yeah, the loops were nested, but I have fixed it now with the solution posted below. This was my first post and I will make sure I more formative next time. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip a quad for each row, e.g. like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 379; i++)
{
    if (i % ROW_LENGTH != ROW_LENGTH - 1) {
      // first triangle
      sample_elements_out.push_back(i);
      sample_elements_out.push_back(i + 1);
      sample_elements_out.push_back(i + samples);

      // second triangle
      sample_elements_out.push_back(i  + samples);
      sample_elements_out.push_back(i + 1);
      sample_elements_out.push_back(i + samples + 1);
    }
}
```

Two nested loops would probably be more readable, though.

Comment: Thank you very much! This has been racking my brain for a while now.

Comment: Np; if this works fine for you, consider accepting the answer as correct.